# Charset of executed

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a problem with my project.
I have a js `function sig7` which generates me hash.

But the charset of `html` page is required to be `utf-8`.

I try to execute this [js](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com) in my `C#` app with library

Everything is OK, but generated hash is not valid. I think it happens because the charset of code isn't `utf-8`.

My app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Noesis.Javascript;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c://lib.js");
            string script = sr.ReadToEnd();

            JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext();
            context.Run(script);
            var sig = context.Run(@"sig7('057d194dd856d4f8cd15bc85fbbddbf136df809f72f5a435e6af41c1f82f950f,Id166084073,ldsclldscl');").ToString();
            richTextBox1.Text = sig;
        }
    }
}
```

sig must be `1dbde1d62b6e0dca7d56f72e50c178132e236978d2dba1e2c3ada5b7b8973aeb` but not `7211ed8fe85d750c26cb5abb499bfa88b7cecbe968fc6cc7efa69dc496c8ae12` which is generated by my app.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should this line:

```
var sig = context.Run(@"sig7('057d194dd856d4f8cd15bc85fbbddbf136df809f72f5a435e6af41c1f82f950f,Id166084073,ldsclldscl');").ToString();
```

Be:

```
var sig = context.Run(@"sig7('057d194dd856d4f8cd15bc85fbbddbf136df809f72f5a435e6af41c1f82f950f', 'Id166084073', 'ldsclldscl');").ToString()
```

?

Comment: @user1993743 Love you too :) Welcome to SO.